# how to fill missing values from a list

Tags: linq

I have an object containing a date and a count.

```
 public class Stat
 {
    public DateTime Stamp {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set ;}
 }
```

I have a Serie object that holds a list of thoses Stat plus some more info such as name and so on...

```
public class Serie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Stat> Data { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Consider that I have a List of Serie but the series don't all contain the same Stamps.
I need to fill in the missing stamps in **all** series with a default value.

I thought of an extension method with signature like this (please provide better name if you find one :) ) :

```
 public static IEnumerable<Serie> Equalize(this IEnumerable<ChartSerie> series, int defaultCount)
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468637/filling-in-missing-dates-using-a-linq-group-by-date-query) seems to treat the same problem, but when querying directly the DB. of course I could loop through the dates and create another list. But is there any more elegant way to achieve this?

i.e.:

Serie A:
01.05.2010 1
03.05.2010 3

Serie B:
01.05.2010 5
02.05.2010 6

I should get :

Serie A :
01.05.2010 1
**02.05.2010 0**
03.05.2010 3

Serie B:
01.05.2010 5
02.05.2010 6
**03.05.2010 0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is elegant enough for you ;-) but since I like Linq, this is what I would have done (using your naming scheme):

```
public static IEnumerable<Serie> Equalize(
    this IEnumerable<Serie> series,
    int defaultCount)
{
    var allStamps = series
        .SelectMany(s => s.Data.Select(d => d.Stamp))
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(d => d)
        .ToList();

    return series.Select(serie => new Serie(
        serie.Name,
        allStamps.Select(d =>
            serie.Data.FirstOrDefault(stat => stat.Stamp == d)
            ??
            new Stat(d, defaultCount))
        ));
}
```

For this code to compile, your classes needs a couple of constructors:

```
public class Stat
{
    public Stat() {}

    public Stat(DateTime stamp, int count)
    {
        Stamp = stamp;
        Count = count;
    }

    public DateTime Stamp { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class Serie
{
    public Serie() {}

    public Serie(string name, IEnumerable<Stat> data)
    {
        Name = name;
        Data = new List<Stat>(data);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Stat> Data { get; set; }
}
```

When calling `series.Equalize(0)` the code above will leave the original instances intact, and return a sequence of newly created `Serie`-instances with their `Data` padded with defaults.

Nothing magic about it. Just the sweetness of Linq... (and the null coalescing operator!)

I haven't tried this with loads and loads of data, so your milage may vary.

Comment: I ended up with a similar solution. I am actually not so sure if linq is really helpful here. It makes it a bit more concise, but how easy is it to understand what that chain of method is doing. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I fully agree with your concern. I'm thinking that the elegance might not be in the implementation of the `Equalize` method, but in the usage. How about sharing what you ended up with?